# Why do these Integration-by-Parts Evaluation Terms Vanish?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

The Associated Legendre operator is
$$
               L_mf = -\frac{d}{dx}\left((1-x^{2})\frac{df}{dx}\right)+\frac{m^{2}}{1-x^{2}}f,
$$
where $m$ is a positive integer. For the purposes here, define the domain $\mathcal{D}(L_m)$ to be the set of twice continuously differentiable real functions on $(-1,1)$ for which $f, L_m f \in L^{2}(-1,1)$.

**Question:** Does anyone know a way to directly verify that
$$
    \int_{-1}^{1}\{ L_m f \}g-f\{ L_m g \} dx = (1-x^{2})\{fg'-f'g\}|_{-1}^{1} = 0,
$$
for all $f,g\in\mathcal{D}(L_m)$? The integral on the left exists because the product of two square integrable functions is absolutely integrable. So the evaluation terms on the right exist as limits at $\pm 1$. The trick is to show that these limits are $0$.

**Background:** The Associated Legendre operators show up when studying the Laplacian on the sphere. It is true that the integration by parts evaluation terms must vanish, and this can be proved indirectly by applying techniques of Functional Analysis to the operator $L_m$. It seems to me that there should be a direct way to verify such a fact using only techniques of Calculus.

This is a curiosity, not some kind of homework problem, or an exercise from a text. I've tried many things and have gotten nowhere. :)

Comment: Maybe functions in $\mathcal D (L_m)$ have to vanish at $\pm 1$ - otherwise I'd expect the $1/(1-x^2)$ term to make the $L^2$ norm diverge. It's a little bit subtle due to the elliptic term but that's what I'd be trying to prove, unless you know a counterexample.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis : Thanks for your comment. Note: I corrected a transcription error in my post where I had omitted the multiplier $(1-x^{2})$ when copying from my notes.

Comment: Seems to make things even easier - just need to show $(1-x^2)f(x) \to 0$ at the endpoints for $f \in \mathcal D$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis : Not easier than what I was working with, but easier than what I first stated here. It's hard to quantify the behavior of $f \in \mathcal{D}(L_m)$  and $f'$ near the endpoints. As you might expect, the evaluation terms do not always vanish in the case where $m=0$.

Comment: Oh, I was assuming too much... unless something unrealistically easy pops out (like the functions being continuous and differentiable on $[0,1]$) I guess it gets ugly.